# Typescript extend two interfaces like type?

Tags: typescript

After reviewing [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) and this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53135199/typescript-interface-cannot-simultaneously-extends-two-types) it looks like the behavior I am looking for is the following:

```
type A = {
  a:string
};
type B = {
  b:string
};

type C = A & B & {
   c:string
};
```

My question is: Can the same behavior be done with interfaces in a single line?

Comment: I vaguely recall seeing a duplicate out there on this question, but I can't find it.

Comment: Please consider giving a [mcve] of what you're trying to do, with enough structure to distinguish good answers from bad answers.  Right now it's a bit *too* minimal: you've got empty object types, so `Primary1` and `Primary2` are equivalent to each other and  `Secondary` is equivalent to just `{prop: string}`.  You can extend multiple interfaces like `interface Secondary extends Primary1, Primary2 { prop: string }`, but I'm not sure if that actually meets whatever use case you have without a little more in the example.

Comment: I made a guess, hopefully that's what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, I updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [extend a comma-separated list of interfaces at once](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#extending-interfaces), as long as the interfaces don't have overlapping properties of differing types:

```
interface Primary1 { prim1: string };
interface Primary2 { prim2: string };
interface Secondary extends Primary1, Primary2 { prop: string }

declare const secondary: Secondary;
secondary.prim1.toUpperCase(); // ok
secondary.prim2.toUpperCase(); // ok
secondary.prop.toUpperCase(); // ok
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApWAWzlAngRmQG9kAHDTfALmQGcwMQBzZAXwG4AoUSWRFdFhy4ATMTIURNeoxYdu4aPCTIAyhAQB7EABNhyCAA9Iu2mgrD8AGnNC8YkuU2lpDUHM6cdGgDY4UWiD0dBraeng06oHhuFy0obrCAHTkWPhJYJoAqqSk0ADCcPEAFACU7MgA9JXImgDWnPHRyamYIhnZuQVFEGUV1bUNTWEtUM4dOXlQhSXlVTX1yJxAA)